# Sort array of objects in JavaScript based on object keys substring

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've got array of objects

```
[
  {
    Severity: "<span class='tableActive'></span>",
    Name: 'U3B',
    'U1A_Shift SCM: UPTT-Pressure (Bara)': '-',
    'U1A_Shift SCM: DPTT-Pressure (Bara)': '-',
    'U3B SCM: APTT-Pressure (Bara)': '3510.00',
    'U3B SCM: UPTT-Pressure (Bara)': '3413.00',
    'U1B SCM: DPTT-Pressure (Bara)': '-',
    'U1B SCM: UPTT-Pressure (Bara)': '-',
    'U3B SCM: DPTT-Pressure (Bara)': '740.00',
    'U1A_Shift SCM: UPTT-Temp (DegC)': '-',
    'U1A_Shift SCM: DPTT-Temp (DegC)': '-',
    'U3B SCM: APTT-Temp (DegC)': '1565.00',
    'U3B SCM: UPTT-Temp (DegC)': '2654.00',
    'U1B SCM: DPTT-Temp (DegC)': '-',
    'U1B SCM: UPTT-Temp (DegC)': '-',
    'U3B SCM: DPTT-Temp (DegC)': '3159.00',
    'U1B SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position': '-',
    'U3B SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position': '-',
    'U1A_Shift SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position': '-',
    Alarms: 0,
    Advisories: 0,
    __row_index: 0,
  },
]
```

Hence output should be

```
[
  {
    Severity: "<span class='tableActive'></span>",
    Name: 'U3B',
    'U1A_Shift SCM: UPTT-Pressure (Bara)': '-',    // grouped by UPTT-Pressure (Bara)
    'U3B SCM: UPTT-Pressure (Bara)': '3413.00',
    'U1B SCM: UPTT-Pressure (Bara)': '-',
    'U1A_Shift SCM: DPTT-Pressure (Bara)': '-',    //grouped by DPTT-Pressure (Bara)
    'U1B SCM: DPTT-Pressure (Bara)': '-',
    'U3B SCM: DPTT-Pressure (Bara)': '740.00',
    'U3B SCM: APTT-Pressure (Bara)': '3510.00', // grouped by APTT-Pressure (Bara)
    'U1A_Shift SCM: UPTT-Temp (DegC)': '-', // grouped by UPTT-Temp (DegC)
    'U3B SCM: UPTT-Temp (DegC)': '2654.00',
    'U1B SCM: UPTT-Temp (DegC)': '-',
    'U1A_Shift SCM: DPTT-Temp (DegC)': '-', // grouped by DPTT-Temp (DegC)
    'U1B SCM: DPTT-Temp (DegC)': '-',
    'U3B SCM: DPTT-Temp (DegC)': '3159.00',
    'U3B SCM: APTT-Temp (DegC)': '1565.00', // grouped by APTT-Temp (DegC)
    'U1B SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position': '-', // grouped by PCV-CHOKE status - Control position
    'U3B SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position': '-',
    'U1A_Shift SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position': '-',
    Alarms: 0,
    Advisories: 0,
    __row_index: 0,
  }
]
```

I need to sort this array of objects based on key name which lies after ":" Eg: APTT-Temp (DegC)

I'm listing only single object I receive array of objects though

I need to sort this array of objects, basically group it by the value of key after ":"(colon)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting an array of objects by object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60942660/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-object-key)

Comment: @biberman : nope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to modify the answer to the following SO question a bit so that it compares the (e.g. integer) values instead of the keys [Sorting an array of objects by object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60942660/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-object-key).
Alternatively you can use the solution for this SO question: [How does sort function work in JavaScript, along with compare function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567941/how-does-sort-function-work-in-javascript-along-with-compare-function)

**Working example**:

```js
var arr = [
  {
    Severity: "<span class='tableActive'></span>",
    Name: 'U3B',
    'U3B SCM: UPTT-Pressure (Bara)': '3413.00',
    'U3B SCM: APTT-Temp (DegC)': '1565.00',
    'U3B SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position': '-',
    'U1A_Shift SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position': '-',
    Alarms: 0,
    Advisories: 0,
    __row_index: 0
  },
  {
    Severity: "<span class='tableActive'></span>",
    Name: 'U3B',
    'U3B SCM: UPTT-Pressure (Bara)': '3413.00',
    'U3B SCM: APTT-Temp (DegC)': '840.00',
    'U3B SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position': '-',
    'U1A_Shift SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position': '-',
    Alarms: 0,
    Advisories: 0,
    __row_index: 0
  },
  {
    Severity: "<span class='tableActive'></span>",
    Name: 'U3B',
    'U3B SCM: UPTT-Pressure (Bara)': '3413.00',
    'U3B SCM: APTT-Temp (DegC)': '1427.00',
    'U3B SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position': '-',
    'U1A_Shift SCM: PCV-CHOKE status - Control position': '-',
    Alarms: 0,
    Advisories: 0,
    __row_index: 0
  }
];

arr.sort( function(a, b) {
  const aValue = parseInt(a['U3B SCM: APTT-Temp (DegC)']);
  const bValue = parseInt(b['U3B SCM: APTT-Temp (DegC)']);
  return aValue - bValue;
});

console.log(arr)
```